# is this Integral equal?

Tags: gamma-function

If:
$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$$
$$z\Gamma(z)=\Gamma(z+1)$$
$$\Gamma(z)=\mathcal \{Me^{-x}\}(z)$$
$$\Gamma(z)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(-x^{z-1})-(-0^ze^{-0})+z\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$$
$$z!=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\Biggl[{1\over{1+{z\over{n}}}}\biggl(1+{1\over n}\biggl)^z\Biggl]\cdot$$
Where $\mathfrak R(z)>0$ and

$$\Gamma(z+1)=z!$$
Where $\mathfrak R(z)>0$
Then is

$$z! = \int_0^\infty x+1^{z-1}e^{-x+1}dx?$$
This is what I did:

$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$$
$$\Gamma(z+1)=z!$$
Then +1 and -1 cancel. Is this right?

Link to gamma function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean $\Gamma(\color{blue}{z})=\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$; $x$ is [integrated over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables#Examples), so doesn't appear on the left-hand side. So $z!=\Gamma(z+1)=\int_0^\infty x^ze^{-x}dx$.

Comment: i edited it by now